# Infinte scroll / masonry 2nd set of images appearing behind first set

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, jquery-masonry, infinite-scroll

Am working on a wordpress site and trying to implement infinte scroll with masonry.

The page in question is here - http://bc.somethingdoing.com/bristol-pubs-bars/?tag=pubs-2

When you scroll down to the bottom of the page to intitiate infinte scroll you should see the new images loading behind the old ones.

It is a bit buggy at the moment but am not sure how to stop the new images loading behind the existign images

The Javascript(JQuery) I am using (in functions.php) is here -

```
 var infinite_scroll = {
                loading: {
                        img: "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/ajax-loader.gif",
                        msgText: "<?php _e( 'Loading the next set of posts...', 'custom' ); ?>",
                        finishedMsg: "<?php _e( 'All posts loaded.', 'custom' ); ?>"
                },
                "nextSelector":"#nav-below  a",
                "navSelector":"#nav-below",
                "itemSelector":".post",
                "contentSelector":"#masonry-container",
        };
        jQuery( infinite_scroll.contentSelector ).infinitescroll( infinite_scroll,// call Masonry as a callback
                function( newElements ) {
                        console.log(newElements);
                        var $newElems = jQuery( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
                        // ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
                                $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
                                console.log('imagesLoded');
                                // show elems now they're ready
                                $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
                                jQuery('#masonry-container').masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true );
                                });
                }
        );
```

Am not sure if its just broken css, misplaced libraries etc.  Am not getting any Javascript errors at the moment , been viewing the site in chrome and FF , having no joy.

Hope thats enough to see what is wrong.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Its an error in masonry script, when the second images load, masonry can't arranged it. so the images can't placed below the old one.its bug in masonry.